# Auto scroll the invisible cell to visible area

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

I have top collection view (top bar) with bottom content collection view i have 4 cell with long text. So in iphone SE i can able to see first two cell clearly. 3rd cell i can able to see only first 2 letters.

Now if i tap on 3rd cell in top collection view content are showing correct. But it still remain in same position, i need to scroll my top collection view to see fully

What i need is if i tap on 3rd cell, it should automatically come to visibe area where i can see full text.For that in did select method i am using like this :

```
 self.bottomCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
```

It is working for 3rd cell. But i want to know will it create issues for other cell. Is that correct approach ?. Will it create any issue for other cells if i tap on first or second cell.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: The method you're using will definitely bring the cell in the visible area depending what position are your passing there. Please add a screenshot so we can have a better idea of what exact code you should use.

Comment: i dont have access to attach from my machine. Thats why posted the question. What is the difference , if i use, right, centeredHorizontally , left. Which one should  i need to use to bring my cel to visible area. Which is right way `left or right or centeredHorizontally`

Comment: It depends on what type of collectionView you're using horizontal or vertical. `left or right or centeredHorizontally` works for horizontal. These decide where the cell should be aligned w.r.t to the collectionView when it is scrolled.

Comment: @PGDev Yes mine is horizontal scrolling . But which one to use` left or right or centeredHorizontally`. Which one is correct way. That i am confused. Because for this 3 its working well.

Comment: Ofcourse they will work fine. They are just the position. You can use any one.